# Piecewise Linear Rayleigh-Ritz

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to get this equation
$-x^2y'' - 2xy' + 2y = -4x^2$

into Piecewise Linear Rayleigh-Ritz format
$-\frac{d}{dx} (p(x) \frac{dy}{dx}) + q(x)y = f(x)$

I pretty much needs to figure out what is $p(x), q(x), f(x)$

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should work out what $ - (p(x)y'(x))'+ q(x)y(x)$ becomes after expanding and compare it to the given expression.

Comment: $$-x^2y'' - 2xy' + 2y = -4x^2 \Rightarrow -(x^2y''+2xy')+2y=-4x^2 \Rightarrow -(x^2y')'+2y=-4x^2$$